# Prevent page scroll up after model refresh in Ember

Tags: dynamic, ember.js, scroll, pagination

I'm adding pagination in our app built on Ember. I'm using `this.refresh()` in the `didQueryParamChange` action inside my router, to refresh the model to get dynamic data every time. This works, but it's making the page scroll to the top, each time you click next.

Is there a way to prevent this? I want my page to stay on the same scroll position even after the model gets refreshed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_queryParams) section of the docs.

Comment: @PatsyIssa That didn't help. :(